# generate -1 / +1 days around a given date in numpy

Tags: arrays, datetime, pandas, numpy

consider a numpy array below:

```
import numpy as np
t = np.array(['2016-07-28', '2016-08-25', '2016-09-29', '2016-10-27', '2016-11-17'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

how can i generate the previous day and next day for each array elements? My desired output would be as below:

```
array(['2016-07-27', '2016-07-28', '2016-07-29', ..., '2016-11-16',
   '2016-11-17', '2016-11-18'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

my current method is to generate the three arrays separately (previous, day, next) and than combine them as below:

```
tt = np.sort(np.append(t1,(t,t2)))
```

Comment: Can you share how are you creating the `t1` and `t2` -1/+1 dates?

Comment: t2= (t + pd.Timedelta(days = 1)).astype('datetime64[D]'); 
t1 = (t - pd.Timedelta(days = 1)).astype('datetime64[D]'). T was created is pd.Series object but i eventually store it as a numpy array. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Broadcast`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) here too!

```
(t[:,None] + np.arange(-1,2)).ravel()
```

A compact version -

```
(t[:,None] + [-1,0,1]).ravel()
```

Sample run -

```
In [191]: t
Out[191]: array(['2016-07-28', '2016-08-25', '2016-09-29', '2016-10-27', '2016-11-17'], dtype='datetime64[D]')

In [192]: (t[:,None] + np.arange(-1,2)).ravel()
Out[192]: 
array(['2016-07-27', '2016-07-28', '2016-07-29', '2016-08-24',
       '2016-08-25', '2016-08-26', '2016-09-28', '2016-09-29',
       '2016-09-30', '2016-10-26', '2016-10-27', '2016-10-28',
       '2016-11-16', '2016-11-17', '2016-11-18'], dtype='datetime64[D]')

In [193]: (t[:,None] + [-1,0,1]).ravel()
Out[193]: 
array(['2016-07-27', '2016-07-28', '2016-07-29', '2016-08-24',
       '2016-08-25', '2016-08-26', '2016-09-28', '2016-09-29',
       '2016-09-30', '2016-10-26', '2016-10-27', '2016-10-28',
       '2016-11-16', '2016-11-17', '2016-11-18'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Comment: very nice solution. much better than mine :-)

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
def f(d):
  return (d-np.timedelta64(1,'D'),d,d+np.timedelta64(1,'D'))

import numpy as np
t = np.array(['2016-07-28', '2016-08-25', '2016-09-29', '2016-10-27', '2016-11-17'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
print np.asarray(map(f,t))
```

Comment: this too works, but i guess, @Divakars' solution is more efficient. thank you